# How to create a Git repository through projects.repos.create api?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-source-repos, google-api-explorer

[The question is very simple](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.repos/create) but [I’m only getting errors](https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/sourcerepo/v1/sourcerepo.projects.repos.create?parent=projects%252Fexample&_h=5&resource=%257B%250A++%2522name%2522%253A+%2522repos%2522%250A%257D&) :

```
POST https://sourcerepo.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<example>/repos?key={YOUR_API_KEY} 
{
 "name": ">repos>"
}
```

Which gives :

```
HTTP/400 
cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  251
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 15 Feb 2018 22:46:47 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
  "details": [
   {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.LocalizedMessage",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "message": "Invalid repo name: repos. Must be of the form projects/<project>/repos/<repo>"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Where `example` is an existing project and repos is the repository name I want to create.

What am I missing ? I failed to find an example of working code.

Comment: Hi @user2284570, have you been able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most important part of the error:

```
{
 ....
    "message": "Invalid repo name: repos. Must be of the form projects/<project>/repos/<repo>"
 ....
}
```

Which tells you that the format of the `name` field is not correct. Let's say you have this settings:

**Project**: your-project-name

**Repo**:    desired-repo-name

Then your request body must be:

```
{
  "name": "projects/your-project-name/repos/desired-repo-name"
}
```

After executing you'll receive the confirmation:

```
200

cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  77
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Wed, 21 Feb 2018 11:12:46 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
 "name": "projects/your-project-name/repos/desired-repo-name"
}
```